# How to get C to ignore spaces?

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings, fgets

I am working on a program that takes in a 32 digit number and inputs it into an array which will then convert it into a int array. However, this 32 digit number includes spaces in between certain areas for example, the number: 11000010111110100000000000000000 could be typed as 1 10000101 11110100000000000000000. 
 When the latter is used, the program would not work. Is there a way for me to get C to ignore the spaces?

 This is my code:

```
int arr[32];
char number[33] = {};
printf("Enter \n");
scanf("%32s", number); // This will scan max 32 characters
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    {
    arr[i] = number[i] - '0';
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't expect `scanf` to be a good solution. It is a function that has limited use. Read a line using `fgets` and parse that.

Comment: I'm unaware of manipulating `scanf` to do this, but the approach I would take is expand the array, read the full line, remove the spaces myself, and then use something like `strtoll` .

Comment: or read the input character by character and decide on each character if you want to use it or not. Something like `char c; while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1) if (isdigit(c)) { /* do something */}`.

Comment: Please explain "ignore the spaces". Do you mean "not stop at a blank, which normally terminates the `%s` format specifier"? Or do you mean "not stop at blank but also not copy it to buffer"? The first one is easy, the second one not. At least not with more changes to your shown code. I have an answer ready for the first one.

Comment: @possum how would one approach the method of removing it by yourself? Would it be using the for loop?

Comment: By the way, I doubt the comment in `scanf("%34s", number); // This will scan max 32 characters`.

Comment: @Yunnosch by ignoring the spaces I want C to take in only 11000010111110100000000000000000 into the array even when 1 10000101 11110100000000000000000 is entered as the input.

Comment: @Yunnosch My bad the comment is not updated

Comment: And do you want that to happen by scanf-magic or are willing to change the rest of your code?

Comment: @Yunnosch if it's possible I would like to maintain the scanf function however if not I am open to changes in my code

Comment: Naming a string `number` is very confusing to me. You could actually get a number with the `<<` operation.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this call of scanf can invoke undefined behavior

```
scanf("%34s", number);
```

because the array number has only 33 elements.

```
char number[33] = {};
```

Moreover the above declaration is not a correct declaration according to the C Standard. You need to write

char number[33] = { 0 };

Also this for loop can be invalid if the string contains embedded spaces or its length is less than 32.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    {
    arr[i] = number[i] - '0';
    }

}
```

As for your question then there are two approaches.

Either write

```
scanf( "%32[^\n]", number );
```

Or use the function `fgets` like

```
fgets( number, sizeof( number ), stdin );
```

In the last case the function can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string. To remove it you can write

```
number[ strcspn( number, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```